# new String(byte[]) broken in Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) on LG devices?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

It seems that `new String(byte[])` is seriously broken in Android 6.0 on the LG LS770 (LG Stylo) device.  Consider the following:

```
byte[] buf = new String("This is a test").getBytes("UTF-8");
int len = buf.length;
String s = new String(buf, "UTF-8");
```

When doing this on an LGLS770 running Android 6.0, `buf` contains the correct byte values, and `buf.length` correctly returns 14, but creating the new String from buf returns the empty string "", when it should return "This is a test".  It doesn't seem to make any difference whether a Charset is specified or not.

Is this a bug just in LG's implementation, or is it a bug in Android 6.0 in general?  The test above worked fine on the same device when it was running Android 5.1.  Can other people try this on different devices running Android 6.0 and report their results?  Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

I was running this in Eclipse, so I thought I would try it in Android Studio instead, since Eclipse is no longer officially supported.  Seems to work fine in Android Studio.  I guess all bets are off for doing Android 6.0 in Eclipse, so I will have to convert all my old projects to Android Studio (sigh)...  Funny how the problem only happened on the device, not the emulator though.

Comment: Have you actually tried this on other devices or an emulator?

Comment: I tried it in the emulator (Nexus 5, Android 6.0, Intel Atom x86_64), and it worked fine there, so I'm thinking this is just an LG bug.  I don't have any other actual Android devices that can be updated to 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

This hack should work on LG with Android 6:

```
String tmpString = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
if (tmpString.length() == 0 && android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    Charset utf8 = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
    tmpString = String.valueOf(utf8.newDecoder().decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer)));
}
```